# Check if string contains HTML? if contains then treat it as normal text

Tags: java, validation

I want to check if string contains HTML. I have "About" field in my form, and there is possibility that user might enter HTML. I will show this info on his/her profile. so here I want to check if it contains HTML before storing it to database. If it contains HTML, i want to keep it as it is, and those HTML tag should be displayed as it is on his her profile as normal text...
How can I achieve this?

And also tell me about any possible threats while taking user info.

Comment: I would have a list of acceptable HTML tags and if there is something you don't accept use `&amp;`

Comment: It would be wise to follow the advice of @PeterLawrey, beware of malicious users that could come up with a [XSS attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)

Comment: Basically there's XSS and SQL Injection along with some others. Have a look at the [OWASP Top 10](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Top_Ten_Project)

Answer (score 6):

What about this here:
http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html
It's an external library though

Answer (score 0):

you will have to look for html tags, using regexps for instance. You will then have to check for correctness of the HTML code (tag closing) and check that their is no malicious code...

Answer (score 0):

Just capture the  tag at the beginning if it is a page with a Stack ADT and implementation. If it is not a whole page, you could capture it with <> signs and peek if it equals some criteria.